# "Map" Numeric to range in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to "map" a number to a range, e.g. `10..20 * 0.5 #-> 15`.

I could write out the maths myself (and extract it to a method for code readability) but if there is a built in method I'd like to know.

Here's the manual labour version I'd like to avoid.

```rb
def map_range(range, t)
  range.first + (range.last - range.first) * t
end
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a builtin method doing this, because such a function looks pretty special. Where could it be used in general? As an alternative implementation, you might consider monkeypatching Range, so that you could call your method as, say `(10..20).mapby(0.5)`. Of course people disagree whether monkeypatching is a good thing or the way to damnation, and you have to make up your mind about this first. Also, think about the semantics of your map_range, if the Range does not consist of numbers, but of (for instance) strings (`'a'..'z'`).

Comment: I'm using something like this quite often. Right now I'm sizing a point in a SketchUp tool based on a max, min and normalized weight value. I've also used it for user input where the user sets a percentage by a slider and only the back end knows what the max and min values are. To me this would make sense to have in the language itself, especially in a lovely language like Ruby.

If I use this often enough within a single project I'll probably refine the range class.

Comment: I don't think 'map' is the correct concept here, what you are actually doing is extracting the max value of a range (`range.first + (range.last - range.first)` is the same thing as just saying `range.last` becuase of the transitive property) and then multiplying it by `t`. So you could just say `range.last * t`. Can you explain a bit more what `map_range` is supposed to do?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with ranges per se, and not with three-dot ranges of floats in any case. You are really asking if, given numbers `x`, `y` and `z`, is there a built-in method to calculate `(y-x)*z`. I am sure there is not.

Comment: Isn't that the same that doing `(range.first + range.last) * t`? (I'm dumb in maths)

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Actually `x+(y-x)*z`. Indeed it would make more sense to define it first on 3 numeric arguments, and if the objects in question are really of type Range, define a new method for the Range, which simply invokes the basic method. Like maxpleaner said in his comment, I also find the name _map_ misleading. I would call such a function _scale_ or maybe _normalize_.

Comment: @SebastianPalma : No. Try to set first=1, last=1, t=10.

Comment: The result of this function divides the interval `range` by ratio `r`; so, I'd be tempted to name the method `Range#divide(r)`? Or maybe `ratio` makes the most sense? Use a refinement, and all moral qualms disappear. ("map" is not incorrect either, as it basically maps a point of [0, 1] interval to another interval; but it is confusing because `map` has an established meaning in programming, separate from mathematics). Given that the "manual labour" is literally three lines of code, five if you use a refinement, I don't see any problem in defining it yourself.